# distinguishing between static and non-static methods in c++ at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, macros, static-methods

For some tracing automation for identifying instances i want to call either:

- a non-static method of the containing object returning its identifier
- something else which always returns the same id

My current solution is to have a base class with a method which() and a global function which() which should be used if not in the context of an object.
This however does not work for static member functions, here the compiler prefers the non-static method over the global one.

Simplified example:

```
class IdentBase
{
public:
  Ident(const std::string& id) _id(id) {}
  const std::string& which() const { return _id; }
private:
  const std::string _id;
};

const std::string& which() { static const std::string s("bar"); return s; }

#define ident() std::cout << which() << std::endl

class Identifiable : public IdentBase
{
public:
  Identifiable() : Ident("foo") {}
  void works() { ident(); }
  static void doesnt_work() { ident(); } // problem here
};
```

Can i somehow avoid using work-arounds like a special macro for static member functions (maybe using some template magic)?

Comment: I'm sure that there's a way doing this by using functions pointers and using some binder for the member function case. But first I'd question the design. Why do you think you need to write the same code in both the static and non-static Identifiable member functions? As so often, "how can I solve this problem?" might have been better than "I'm stuck on this way to solve my problem, how do I get further?"

Comment: i want to use the same code because i want to simply use one central macro instead of one for static and one for non-static contexts.
maybe the design isn't right, but at least i don't see a better one myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to to use  [is_member_function_pointer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_member_function_pointer.html) from the Boost TypeTraits library.  sbi's suggestion of using different code in the static and non-static cases is probably better though.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function template that returns a default identifier for all types.

```
template<typename T>
const std::string& which(const T& object)
{ static const std::string s("bar"); return s; }
```

Specialize the function template for the specific class.

```
class IdentBase
{
public:
    IdentBase(const std::string& id): _id(id) {}
    const std::string& id() const { return _id; }
private:
    const std::string _id;
};

template<>
const std::string& which(const IdentBase& object)
{ return object.id(); }
```

Call the function template by passing an instance that you want to identify.

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    std::cout << which(i) << std::endl;

    IdentBase foo("foo");
    std::cout << which(foo) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but i don't see where that would allow me to invoke which() in one central macro without different code for static/non-static contexts.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your requirement for a no-argument macro to identify the instance.  My solution requires you to pass the instance as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a different identifier for every instance of each class as in your example, or are you just trying to identify which class is in the trace?

Changing your which() function and _id member to static would expose them both to your static member functions, and as a bonus decrease your memory usage.

Comment: yes, i do that in order to identify different instances of the same class and their childs.

Comment: And in that case, what is the static method for and why does it have to have the same body? Otherwise you could a) pass the ident macro (or function) what to print (this->which() or ::which()), or you could implement the static like: { using ::which; ident(); }

Comment: my aim is to use one collection of mostly "automatic" trace/log macros and not any specific ones depending on the context. these should also, as far as possible, automatically log what main instance they belong to.
{using ::which(); ...} would contradict the aim of simplicity&automatization, as would be passing explicit messages.
call me lazy, but i dont wan't to think about in which context i am if i can somehow automate that.

Comment: So you are saying that you don't want to change the calling code and you don't want to change the macro? You just want your idea to "work"?

Comment: Nope, i'm saying i don't want to introduce an additional macro. And i don't wan't to use anything around the macro to make it work in certain contexts. I simply want a generic macro that works in all contexts.

Comment: Well I can't think of a way to tell inside the macro, what kind of function you are in.